# What could be the possible intention of inheritance here

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on existing code base(Asp.net web api). There I encountered following class, and it made me think in which case this will be useful? So far I have seen the code base, it has not been used anywhere yet. As it inherits Exception Class, so I think generic Exception class  could be used instead making this new one. Could someone shed light on this i.e. when do we need such customized class and how it can be helpful?

** The developer who has defined this has gone.

```
public class HttpResponseException : Exception
{
    private string _message;

    public HttpResponseException() : base() { }
    public HttpResponseException(string message) : base(message)
    {
        this._message = message;
    }

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this._message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The name of the class is self explanatory and shows intent. As it should be.

Comment: If it's not being used anywhere then it seems the intent was lost.  Generally one creates custom exceptions for the purpose of *throwing* and *catching* those custom exceptions.  They could contain custom information, though that's not necessary.  But simply being a custom type allows one to treat it differently by giving it a targeted `catch` block.  (There are also those who consider catching the general `Exception` to be very poor form, always preferring specific exception types.)

Comment: @David has it right. The type is just a tag which allows catching code to distinguish it from other execptions, in order  to handle it differently. One could as well have just one exception type, catch each with the same catch and then if/elseif over them by some other criteria, handling those specially which meet one while re-throwing all others. I think it's clear how much better the "type tag" is compared to other tags, not least because it comes with a free built-in hierarchy system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Take a look at exception handling for web apis.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) The class in your post seems to provide similar functionality as [HttpResponseException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.httpresponseexception?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

It is helpful to have more specific exceptions so you can uniquely react to them rather than throw general exceptions because then you don't know the specific details in regards to what went wrong when catching it (you just know something went wrong and have to guess what those scenarios could be).

Take a look at [The best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-specific-exceptions-in-a-catch-block) and [how to use specific exceptions in a catch block.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions) I think this statement describes the thought behind this class

> In general, it's good programming practice to catch a specific type of exception rather than use a basic catch statement.

**Why did the developer implement this HTTPException class which already exists in the following HttpResponseException?**

I can think of the following scenarios.

- The developer may not have known HttpResponseException existed as per the documentation I provided earlier.
- Maybe this project was in an old enough version of .net where http exceptions did not exist at the time.
- **Most Likely scenario IMOP** - The developer wanted to provide some functionality that was unique for HTTP exceptions and this was their placeholder to implement it though they never got around to finishing that implementation.

The current implementation of this class provides no unique functionality compared to what is available in web APIs and you can most likely remove it and use the Exceptions that are built in.